# Javascript ReferenceError: $ is not defined using bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On my following website every function that related to javascript (using bootstrap framework) isn't working properly. Today when I began to work on it the application worked fine and the only thing I changed on the website that could affect the page itself / all pages that the website contains is the navigation bar that I edited when I added a simple green button, that when I delete it will not fix the error. I've been searching and testing for days and can't find the solution.

Whenever I view the error logs there is one simple error

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined (index.php:110)

that refers to

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {        
    $('.carousel').carousel()
        });
</script>
```

which should only affect the home page as this file is not called on any other part of the website.

However, as I don't know where to start searching in the code for this error, I can't really post the whole code here. However it can be viewed on the link above. I'm actually just searching for a position to start fixing or looking for some typos or whatever, but I got confused because it worked before I added a PHP-script which doesn't affect the websites state at all.

Any clues? Thanks for answers.

Comment: *"Description without code (as I don't know where exactly the error could be and therefore can't post the whole website's code here):"* Nope, not how it works. More: http://sscce.org

Comment: http://bit.ly/1nWppcH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the jquery file is not properly linked.

You have to consider that your main html has to link to the custom javascript code AND a javascript library code, wich can be hosted in your local server or somewhere in the internet.

Make sure you have something like this in the body of your Html file, and **before** your custom js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahh.. there we go. I included it at the bottom of the page, and therefore whenever I get an error at any position of my code the browser stops at this line and won't load the jquery.

Comment: You have to place it somewhere inside `<head>` and `</head>`. hope it helps!

Comment: Problem here is taking the advice from bootstrap or in general getting beter rendering times as the pages load before jquery. Which might be true but then something like this happens..

Comment: @chriszo111: invicente said *"You have to place it somewhere inside `<head>` and `</head>`"* You ***don't*** have to put it within `head`, and in fact doing so is an anti-pattern. You just have to include it before you try to use it, just like you have to open a door before stepping through it. That can be in the `head` (although at the cost of perceived load time), or at the bottom just before the closing `</body>` tag, which is the usual recommendation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , I'm not sure about that, have you some resources about it? For what i know, it is reccomendable to place all the links to libraries and external files (css files, e.g.) in the head. However The actual Js code for functions and such should be placed, as you said, somewhere before you want to use it  in the body... But please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @invicente: Nope, it's CSS in the head, JS in the body, unless you have a really, really good reason to do something else. One quite well-known resource for this is YUI's guidelines: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the jQuery library. Be sure you load it before all your javascript code and before bootstrap library also.

You should load bootstrap after jQuery, and you should execute the code below only after you load `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('.carousel').carousel()
});
```

Note: Any code that has to do with $ it's linked to jQuery, so you have to use it after (not before) the jQuery library. I recommend you to use all your Javascript code just before the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library is not loaded yet - or at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I included it just not at the top but at the bottom.